# Iterating in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

Ultimate goal is to pull data from a Feature Class, group out the different types of Lease Status (field), run a dissolve and sum calculation on each new layer/FC then merge all new layers/FC's together into one FC.

This is my manual process for what I am trying to accomplish: I went about creating a table that includes one Tract_ID, the lease_status and a sum calculated on the Percent_interest field for all the owners. (probably very rudimentary LOL)

*(create initial  tables to work from)*

- Export DBLeaseOR8312m into a new layer/FC for each lease_status  for example DBLeaseOR8312m_open, DBLeaseOR8312m_ThirdParty, etc.
- From the DBLeaseOR8312m_open FC select all other lease_statuses and delete
- Run dissolve on the new layer

  - Select Tract_ID as the dissolve field
  - Select percent_interest and “SUM” in the statistics area

*(modify new tables to include new field)*

- This creates a new table that only has one Tract_ID, one type of Lease_status and the percent_interest calculated for all owners and included in percent interest field.
- Creat new field in this table for Lease_status and add the specific type to that field
- Do this for each Lease_status type

*(merge data together into one final table)*

- Then merge all tables into one table to include all lease_status types.

I'm thinking I can use Iterate Feature Selection in model builder but not quite sure how to bring it all together and set my outputs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to run such things from a file geodatabase to keep all the fields consistent for field mapping in your model.

If I interpreted correctly you want to: 1. split your FC by lease type.
2. Dissolve each resulting FC on the lease type and sum the percent interest for that lease type.
3. and then combined all FC's back together.

From what I have gathered, starting with multiple iterations of the "Select" tool will work to split your feature class by Lease type. You will need to make sure you have a selection for each possible Lease type in your model, and that the attribute values are consistent. 
Then add the dissolve tool to each of the outputs from the select. When you open the properties of the dissolve tool you should see the list of fields from the select output. Check the fields you want to dissolve on. The others will be dropped from your attribute table. (Don't check your interest field since you want to sum that value). Instead at the bottom of the dissolve tool properties window you will see the statistics field option. Add the interest field there and choose the "SUM" option. 
Then use the "Merge" tool to combined all the outputs from the dissolve tool back together.

Comment: Thanks Tyler!! I also use file geodatabases. As for your instructions they are exactly what I am looking to do. I think by looking over the link Artwork21 listed I might be able to move further in creating this model using your "multiple" iteration idea. I was actually not sure if when using iterations, the information was stored in "memory" of some sort to be used in the next processes... I'm really clueless right now LOL

Comment: So I have created a model off your suggestions however I'm not quite sure what you mean by multiple iterations since I know we can only add one iteration per model unless nested or subbed. What I have so far is: (DBLease Feature Class) - (Iterate Feature Selection) - which throws off (I_DBLeaseOR_lease_status) and (value) then I run my (dissolve on Tract_ID and statistical calculation "SUM" on Percent_int) ouputs - (DBLeaseOR_Dissolve)  but it shows an error during the iteration "Failed selecting with "lease_status" = 'open', An expected field was not found or could not be retrieved

Comment: got it to work!!! was running iteration on a FC with a join. To make more stable i ran copy features to FC which worked. but now I think need to set a precondition so that the iteration runs on all variables before processing the dissolve. Currently it's running each iteration and doing dissolve on each one... anyway, I'll stop bothering you, Thanks again for all your help!!! : )

Comment: I'm glad its working for you. Note that your model will process in the order that you built it in. So if you added all of your "select" tools in first it will run through them first before moving to the dissolve. It shouldn't effect your results though. As far as my multiple iterations I was just referring to the multiple instances of the select tool you would need to split your FC by lease type. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple resources that you might find helpful for performing iterations.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Selection/00400000000s000000/

[Getting to Know Model Builder](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=195&moduleID=0)

Comment: Artwork21, Thanks so much! I had gone over the iterations desktop help but really I needed to step back to this link! I am good with simple model builder tasks but not large models using iteration and such.