# ArcMap Model Builder Iterator to create selections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iterator

This is a sequel to my question about [aggregating polygons in order to create neighborhoods](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76923/create-a-single-connected-polygon-from-multiple-polygons).

I want to automate the geoprocessing of the above task.  When I use Model Builder's "Iterate Feature Selection" iterator I get the below error:

[image]

I originally tried to link the "Iterate Feature Selection" iterator directly to the Aggregate Polygon tool.  But [as per this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65055/how-to-iterate-through-only-select-attributes-of-a-single-field-using-modelbuild) I inserted the Make Feature layer tool in between.  (Now removed, see comments below)

[image]

My problem is I'm unsure how to link the iterator's selection to the input of the Aggregate Polygon tool.  Really, **why does the GROUP BY function of "iterate feature selection" iterator not create a complete SQL condition statement??**

The following threads have proved un-useful as well:

[Iterating in ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22137/model-builder-question-regarding-iterations-newbe)

[Model builder: select feature based on attribute, iterator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37421/model-builder-select-feature-based-on-attribute-iterator)

thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions: "Why does the GROUP BY function of 'iterate feature selection' iterator not create a complete SQL condition statement?" and "Why does Make Feature Layer give Error 000230?".  I think you should edit this Question to focus on one or the other and then research/ask the other one separately.  The second question looks like the easier one to resolve so I recommend focussing on that first.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo, but error 000230 explicitly says that the error resulted from "An invalid SQL statement was used."  I thought this implies a focus on the question I asked about the group by function.

Comment: I can remove the part about the error if others agree with you...

Comment: The Iterate Feature Selection already creates a feature layer that can be added as the input the the Aggregate GP tool.  I do not think you need the extra Make Feature Layer.  You might need to add a new field to your input polygons that will form your selection groups.

Comment: @amarinel I initially attempted without the make feature layer tool only to receive the same result.  I'll go back and add the (simple) model to my question (see above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the model that I created which ran through rather successfully (i.e. created the necessary feature classes and tables but had a generic error at the end for an unknown reason [to be honest I am not incredibly familiar with this tool or the Cartography suite])

My thoughts are not to worry about the Group by field not running a full SQL statement.  Do the work beforehand by using select by attributes or select by location to select field and add an identifier in a new field.  Thereby creating your "selections" in a new field as shown in the polygon FC in my example with the [CDCODE] field.  Also note the inline variables on the output of the Aggregate Polygon tool.

How do the parameters of the model you just posted differ?

[image: Aggregate Polygon Mmodel]

[Full size Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IggjD.png)

Comment: thanks @amarinel, I found an error in the data, corrected it and adjusted parameters to match your example above.  Now I get the following errors: ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Item not found in this collection.
Failed to execute (Make Feature Layer).
Failed at Tue Dec 24 11:48:33 2013 (Elapsed Time: 8.00 seconds)
Failed to execute (Iterate Feature Selection).  The [ArcGis Help for Iterate feature Selection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Selection/00400000000s000000/) mentions nothing about constraints on data type.

Comment: [Error: 000354](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp00000026000354.htm)

Comment: Check your file and feature class names once again for special symbols and spaces.  Are you still using Make Feature Layer in your model?  How many fields are you using in the parameter Group by Field?

Comment: ok, I was ignoring some empty values. I populated the nulls with a "dummy" value and the model is running!  thanks for the assistance!